# How to instantiate a class

Tags: java, graphiti

I have a problem in my application , I can't instantiate a class

this is my `java.lang.ClassCastException`

```
eclipse.emf.editeurgraphique.risque.features.StartEventFeature$CreateStartEventFeature cannot be cast to org.eclipse.graphiti.features.ICreateFeature 
at eclipse.emf.editeurgraphique.risque.features.StartEventFeature.getCreateFeature(StartEventFeature.java:43)
```

And this is my method :

```
 public ICreateFeature getCreateFeature(IFeatureProvider fp) {
    return (ICreateFeature) new CreateStartEventFeature(fp);
}
```

my Interface :

```
public interface ICreateFeature extends ICreate, IFeature {
 }
```

and my class

```
 public CreateStartEventFeature(IFeatureProvider fp) {
        super(fp, "Start Event", "Indicates the start of a process or    choreography");
    }
```

Comment: Where is the class definition for CreateStartEventFeature, does it implement ICreateFeature?

Comment: Can  you please show the declaration of the `CreateStartEventFeature` class, not just its constructor, so that we can see what's wrong and how best to fix it?  The problem isn't in the code that you've shown here.

Comment: If and only if CreateStartEventFeature can really be casted into ICreateFeature, it could be a classpath problem.. or you have used more than one (different) classloaders (loading a jar twice or so..).

Answer (score 0):

Your CreateStartEventFeature does not extend any class defined by you, so by calling super constructor

```
super(fp, "Start Event", "Indicates the start of a process or    choreography");
```

you try ro run parametrized constructor from Object class.

Comment: No.  If what you're saying were true, this program wouldn't compile.  But Ines has an exception when she runs the program, so it must compile.

Answer (score 0):

CreateStartEventFeature needs to implement the interface:

```
public class CreateStartEventFeature extends MyBaseClass implements ICreateFeature 
{...}
```

Comment: No.  Look at the constructor for `CreateStartEventFeature`.  There must be a superclass with a very specific constructor.  So the declaration will need more than what you've shown here.

Comment: That doesn't mean it can't implement the interface as well.

Comment: Sure, obviously.  Now that you've edited your answer, it makes more sense.

Answer (score 0):

The question is a bit confusing since it doesn't show the whole problem, but I assume CreateStartEventFeature implements ICreateFeature, so try leaving out the explicit cast:

```
public ICreateFeature getCreateFeature(IFeatureProvider fp) {
    return new CreateStartEventFeature(fp);
}
```